# Problems connecting to Vino server on Lubuntu from Windows 10 VNC client

Tags: lubuntu, vnc, vino

I run Vino using these commands on my Lubuntu 18.04 machine:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
/usr/lib/vino/vino-server --display=:0
```

When I try to connect to machine from a RealVNC client on a Windows 10 machine I see a blank black screen for a few seconds, then the session terminates itself.

Any ideas for diagnosing/fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

This happens if you have "prompt-enabled" set to true - the server prompts for permission to allow the remote client, and if it doesn't receive a response the connection times out.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino prompt-enabled false
```

Then restart vino-server.

Comment: Wow ! I had the same problem with a brand new Linux Mint 20.1 and it finally fixed the problem ! Many thanks. I upvote this entry.